# Python ECDSA Public Key Recovery

Tags: signature, python, encryption, ecdsa

How do you recover the EC public key from a VRS style signature in python?

I am trying to setup some encryption between two parties via ECIES, but I first wanted to obtain the public key via recovery from a transaction. The following is an example transaction from my geth console I've been working with.

```
eth.getTransaction("0x912b33e09311a72b988af66918abcd53f43831688c7acb6b44870c491f073dab")
{
  blockHash: "0xfdc5a1c9e1a0dcdfb2b9884919b79157a04eb15b0b58c91131e957f2803f8195",
  blockNumber: 100449,
  from: "0xc6f4f527587ea4a03aa85e0322783592367c1b9a",
  gas: 100000,
  gasPrice: 18000000000,
  hash: "0x912b33e09311a72b988af66918abcd53f43831688c7acb6b44870c491f073dab",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 21,
  r: "0xab90122dc4e4bbdbb14ef22ad3ae21aecc19a1c90a9c8989c68b26cc782ff303",
  s: "0x36e5f275147049d3afd5d33b735cc9313d2c1aad3ab401aefdce678128e2f1d0",
  to: "0xa593094cebb06bf34df7311845c2a34996b52324",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1c",
  value: 1000000000000
}
web3.sha3(eth.getRawTransaction("0x912b33e09311a72b988af66918abcd53f43831688c7acb6b44870c491f073dab"),{encoding:'hex'})
"0x912b33e09311a72b988af66918abcd53f43831688c7acb6b44870c491f073dab"
```

From the transaction above, I have the raw material for the signature (e.g., V, R, S) and the sender (i.e., "from" field) which I can use to verify the address.

I'm trying to do this in python.

```
sender = "0xc6f4f527587ea4a03aa85e0322783592367c1b9a"
hash = "0x912b33e09311a72b988af66918abcd53f43831688c7acb6b44870c491f073dab"
r = "0xab90122dc4e4bbdbb14ef22ad3ae21aecc19a1c90a9c8989c68b26cc782ff303"
s ="0x36e5f275147049d3afd5d33b735cc9313d2c1aad3ab401aefdce678128e2f1d0"
v = "0x1c"
import bitcoin
import ethereum.keys #for a good sha3 implementation
from rlp.utils import decode_hex, encode_hex
rawhash = decode_hex(hash[2:]) # omit the 0x
vrs = (int(v[2:],16),int(r[2:],16),int(s[2:],16)) # omit the 0x and convert to integers based on base16 (hex)
rec_pub = bitcoin.ecdsa_raw_recover(rawhash,vrs) ## Trouble line!
enc_rec_pub = bitcoin.encode_pubkey(rec_pub,"bin")
rec_address = encode_hex(ethereum.keys.sha3(enc_rec_pub[1:]))[24:]
if rec_address == sender[2:]:
    print "[+++] The address was recovered from the public key! :-)"
else:
    print "[-] This address is not the same :-("
```

The ecdsa_raw_recover never results in the correct value. I've opened up the keyfile to verify the public/private key and the following line never results in the correct value.

```
rec_pub = bitcoin.ecdsa_raw_recover(rawhash,vrs)
```

Is there some aspect to this that I am missing or a better recommendation on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `rawhash` you used is not right!

Read this: [How to generate the rawhash in python](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/ecb14c937a0b6cb0a0dc4f06be3a88e6d53dcce3/ethereum/transactions.py#L74?L81).

Since you have the package `ethereum` in you code, the simplest way to get public key is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rlp
import ethereum
import ethereum.transactions


class MyTransaction(ethereum.transactions.Transaction):

    _publickey = None

    @property
    def publickey(self):
        secpk1n = ethereum.transactions.secpk1n
        if not self._publickey:
            if self.v in (27, 28):
                vee = self.v
                rlpdata = rlp.encode(
                    self, ethereum.transactions.UnsignedTransaction)
            elif self.v >= 37:
                vee = self.v - self.network_id * 2 - 8
                assert vee in (27, 28)
                rlpdata = rlp.encode(
                    rlp.infer_sedes(self).serialize(self)[:-3] \
                    + [self.network_id, '', ''])
            else:
                return None  # Invalid V value
            if self.r >= secpk1n or self.s >= secpk1n or self.r == 0 \
                    or self.s == 0:
                return None  # Invalid signature values!
            sighash = ethereum.utils.sha3(rlpdata)
            pub = ethereum.utils.ecrecover_to_pub(sighash, vee, self.r, self.s)
            if pub == b'\x00' * 64:
                return None  # Invalid signature (zero privkey cannot sign)
            self._publickey = pub
        return self._publickey

    @publickey.setter
    def publickey(self, value):
        self._publickey = value


def main():
    nonce = 21
    gasprice = 18000000000
    startgas = 100000
    to = '0xa593094cebb06bf34df7311845c2a34996b52324'
    value = 1000000000000
    data = ''
    sender = "0xc6f4f527587ea4a03aa85e0322783592367c1b9a"
    r = "0xab90122dc4e4bbdbb14ef22ad3ae21aecc19a1c90a9c8989c68b26cc782ff303"
    s ="0x36e5f275147049d3afd5d33b735cc9313d2c1aad3ab401aefdce678128e2f1d0"
    v = "0x1c"
    r = int(r, 16)
    s = int(s, 16)
    v = int(v, 16)
    tx = MyTransaction(nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, v, r, s)
    assert sender[2:] == ethereum.utils.sha3(tx.publickey)[-20:].hex()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What if you only have the signature and v, r, s values?