# Can not retrieve Ethereum address form transaction signature on Python

Tags: signature

I'm trying to retrieve the ethereum address from the transaction signature. I have got the following transaction:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x82388a80a654586ec646115ae63a664e594e0e34dd6fb20dcf078d9495788578",
  blockNumber: 4311,
  from: "0x6825487b18c45c507d06b44ec2ba5b5bf3925f23",
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: 100000000000,
  hash: "0x0fe0a5142f41e516f55017c03c173ea59382f7554a4d3e9efabd12b35734da32",
  input: "0xfdacd5760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
  nonce: 249,
  r: "0x5897c2c7c7412b0a555fb6f053ddb6047c59666bbebc6f5573134e074992d841",
  s: "0x1c71d1c62b74caff8695a186e2a24dd701070ba9946748318135e3ac0950b1d4",
  to: "0xccfaed4390d5e757476f657bf96146570126188d",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0xa96",
  value: 0
}
```

Following Ethereum yellow paper I would have to do the following to retrieve the `from` address `0x6825487b18c45c507d06b44ec2ba5b5bf3925f23`:

`S(T) ≡ B 96..255(KEC(ECDSARECOVER(h(T), Tw ,Tr ,Ts))))`

Where the values in my case is (Python code):

```
Tw = long("1c",16)
Tr = long("5897c2c7c7412b0a555fb6f053ddb6047c59666bbebc6f5573134e074992d841",16)
Ts = long("1c71d1c62b74caff8695a186e2a24dd701070ba9946748318135e3ac0950b1d4",16)
Thash = long("0fe0a5142f41e516f55017c03c173ea59382f7554a4d3e9efabd12b35734da32",16)
```

Then:

```
x,y=ecdsa_raw_recover(bin(Thash), (v, r, s))
k = sha3.keccak_256()
k.update(str(x)+str(y))
k.hexdigest()
```

But I'm getting `8485031e62b6cf0ea13a32580e00b8ce77d614443f1a14a1f1495cfc48e985a7` instead of `6825487b18c45c507d06b44ec2ba5b5bf3925f23`.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong? I don't know if I'm missing some convertion or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Albert.

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/python-ecdsa-public-key-recovery.